# Issue with Running Two Separate Codes on Intel Cyclone V SoC ARM Cortex A9 Dual Core via QSPI

Tags: arm, intel-fpga, soc, cyclone, multicore

I am working on an Intel Cyclone V SoC ARM Cortex A9 Dual Core setup and aiming to execute two distinct codes on Core 0 and Core 1 in bare-metal mode. While I've successfully executed this setup using JTAG debugging, where I sequentially debugged Core 0 followed by Core 1 after taking it out of reset, I'm encountering a problem when attempting to run both cores via QSPI flash.

Despite combining both programs into a single image file, Core 1 fails to execute as expected. In the linker/scat file, Core 0's entry point is specified as 0x60000, and Core 1's entry point is set to 0x9fff0. **However, upon execution, Core 0 behaves correctly, while Core 1's program counter jumps to 0xFEBAF5E8 instead of its designated entry point.**

Your insights or suggestions on resolving this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**Core 0 firmware and linker file**

```
#include "HAL/hal_common.h"
#include "HAL/hal_timer.h"
#include "alt_mmu.h"
#include "alt_cache.h"
//#include "hwlib.h"

typedef int32_t             ALT_STATUS_CODE;

#define ARRAY_COUNT(array)  (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

#define RSTMGR_MPUMODRST_OFFSET 0x10 // offset
#define RSTMGR_MPUMODRST_ADDR (0xFFD05000 + RSTMGR_MPUMODRST_OFFSET)

#define RSTMGR_CPU1_ADDR 0xFFD080C4
void main(void)
{
    // Initialize HAL
    HAL_Init();
    TIM_Init();
    TIM_Preset();
    volatile uint32_t* cpu1startaddr = (uint32_t*)0xFFD080C4;
    *cpu1startaddr = 0x9fff0 ;   // cpu1 reset exception address 0x160010

    //*pPreLoaderStateReg = BL_CONFIG_PRELOADER_STATE_VALID;
    uint32_t reg_val = *(volatile uint32_t *)RSTMGR_MPUMODRST_ADDR;
    reg_val &= ALT_RSTMGR_MPUMODRST_CPU1_CLR_MSK;
    *(volatile uint32_t *)RSTMGR_MPUMODRST_ADDR = reg_val; // taking core 1 out of reset from core 0

    while (1)
    {

            // functionality we want to achieve from core 0 also it take core 1 out of reset already

}

}
```

**Scat file**

```
SDRAM 0x00060000 0x40000
;0x40000
; 0x62250
{
    ; Vector Table
    VECTORS +0
    {
        * (VECTORS, +FIRST)
    }    
    
    ; Application Code
    APP_CODE +0
    {
        * (+RO, +RW, +ZI)
    }
    
    ; 256 Byte stack
    ARM_LIB_STACK +0 EMPTY 0x0100
    { }  
    
    ; 64kB Heap (not used)
    ARM_LIB_HEAP +0 EMPTY 0x010000
    { }    
}
```

**Core 1 firmware and linker file**

```
#include "HAL/hal_common.h"

//#include "HAL/hal_timer.h"

/**
 * Bootloader Main Function
 */
void main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
//  TIM_Init();
//  TIM_Preset();
    uint32_t   ii=0;
    uint8_t    led_status=0;
    while (1)
    {
        // functionality we want to achieve from core 1
}
}
```

**Scat file**

```
SDRAM_CORE1 0x9fff0 0x6c960

{
    ; Vector Table
    VECTORS +0
    {
        * (VECTORS, +FIRST)
    }    
    
    ; Application Code
    APP_CODE +0
    {
        * (+RO, +RW, +ZI)
    }
    
    ; 256 Byte stack
    ARM_LIB_STACK +0 EMPTY 0x0100
    { }  
    
    ; 64kB Heap (not used)
    ARM_LIB_HEAP +0 EMPTY 0x010000
    { }    
}
```